# Can I move plot-specific buildings ?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Is it possible to destroy, then rebuild plot-specific single buildings, such as the alien containment or officer school?

Will I lose anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. You will only lose money and building time.

In particular, destroying and rebuilding alien containment is a way to kill all aliens in it, so you'd have their corpses for the Grey Market or Council Requests. This is the only way to kill of duplicate aliens, as you can interrogate particular kind of alien only once. Duplicate aliens just sit in the Alien Containment forever, providing no added value whatsoever.

Comment: Interrogating a live alien automatically generates a corpse, anyway. Yes, I've checked. :)

Comment: @Shadur: you're right, I'll edit

Comment: Huh, interesting. Did not know this - I'll have to keep it in mind for future playthroughs (as capturing redundant aliens is a fairly cheep way to outfit squads with some basic plasma weaponry)

Comment: @TrentHawkins: another way of getting equipment is letting mind controlled alien get killed. Downside -- you get temporary will debuff ("fallen comrades")

Answer (score 2):

You can with some of them, but not others. The Gollop Chamber and the Hyperwave Relay cannot be demolished once you've built them, so try to build them where they will not mess up your base's layout. You'll spend time, money and materials rebuilding demolished facilities, as well their use - demolishing an officer school will deactive all the upgrades you've bought there until you build a new one, for example.

Comment: do the "purchased" upgrades come back? or do I need to re-buy them?

Comment: They do come back as soon as you rebuild the school.